# Browser back button: I always stay on the current page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and I have this code:
HTML template:
`<a href="" ng-click="goToCategories();">See categories</a>`
JS File:

```
$scope.goToCategories= function () {
                CategoriesService.getCategory().then(function () {
                    $state.go('home.cat');
                });
            };
```

JS File 2:

```
$stateProvider.state('home.cat', {
        parent: 'logged',
        url: '/cat',
        templateUrl: 'home/home-cat.html',
        ...
    });
```

The problem is when we are at `home-cat.html`, the browser back button doesn't work. I just stay in `home-cat.html`. How to correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a plunker?

Comment: I don'k think that I can put a plunkr for this question... I don't know if I am wrong but, since my problem is related to the back button browser, I don't see how I could reproduce the problem in plunkr...

Answer (score 2):

First is 'logged' a route that has a URL or is it an abstract route?

Second does the place where you are coming from with the link have a unique URL?

Third are you aware you told $state.go to go to a route that doesn't exist?

```
$state.go('home.cat');
```

should probably be

```
$state.go('home.funnel');
```

If you could setup a plunkr or jsfiddle that would also help :)

Note: you don't need

```
<a href="" ng-click="goToCategories();">See categories</a>
```

you can simply use

```
<a ui-sref="home.funnel">See categories</a>
```

or

```
<a ui-sref="home.funnel({ param: value})">See categories</a>
```

docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Comment: Normally answers don't include multiple questions about the original question. They should've ben comments on the original question.

Comment: @KeniSteward: 'logged' is an abstract route, the place where I come from with the link has a unique URL, and it's home.cat not .funnel. I will edit my question... Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I can't comment because I just joined